# Send/Requestion Token evevery page/request

Tags: java, angularjs, cookies, service

im doing a simple login page:

```
<div class="form-signin" role="form" ng-controller="loginController">

                <div class="center-block" ng-repeat="erro in erros">
                    <span class="error">{{erro.message}}</span>
                </div>
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Identifique-se</h2>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Endereço de Email" ng-model="usuario.email" autofocus>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" ng-model="usuario.senha" required>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox"  value="remember-me"> Lembrar Dados
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="Logar()" type="submit">Entrar</button>
            </div>
```

it do a POST to "/MyService/Example/Login" javaee backend using the usuario.email and usuario.senha fields, i can read and return true or not normally, but my doubt is, how can i implement a Token? im already generating a token using the UUID random + useremail + creation time. I have to send it with the JSON? i have to do a request.addHeader in the backend and add the token there? and how can i implement a kind of service that EVERY page it do a "requestLogin", so when users login for first time it send a blank token-cookie, after login server return the cookie, user store in the cookie, and for every page/request it send the token-cookie back and i can verify if its authentic, if not, send false and than angular return to the login page?!

i mean, im not asking for code, i saw some tutorials about token + angular, but was "simple" to understand explaining why and how to use the thing =\

Comment: use HttpSession, Web server will take the responsibility of cookie validation.

Comment: thanks the answer, but i need to learn token too..

Comment: unique session id JSESSIONID {cookie} is stored in client machine